# Can I raise an exception from pdb? (for debugging)

Tags: python, debugging, exception, try-catch, pdb

Let's say I have:

```
def fn1():
    # do some work
    # in some cases raise exception

def fn2():
    # do some work
    try:
        fn1()
    except:
        # do some work
```

I want to test the negative path by raising an exception from within pdb. 
I tried from `fn1`:

```
(Pdb) raise cliexceptions.NoConnectionError("Could not connect")
*** NoConnectionError: 'Could not connect to SSR'
```

It prints the msg but does not exit `fn1`.
Is there a way to do that?

Comment: i guess no you can't. that request is too bazaar. i think you can pack the code in your except block and test it as a function.

Comment: yes but isn't it much easier to be able to test from pdb instead of wrapping every code in the except block and test as a function?

Comment: now you are asking a question. so how could that be easier? why should debugger affect the workflow of the program anyway? it is purely not the design goal of debugger and thus it's natural to be unsupported.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually (partially) simulate the impact of an exception, by jumping to the appropriate line in the `except` clause, and in case you also catch an exception object (which in your case you don't), explicitly create it.

```
# a.py
line1@ def fn2():
line2@    # do some work
line3@    try:
line4@        fn1()
line5@    except:
line6@        print 'exception'

(Pdb) b 4
(Pdb) c
> a.py(4)fn2()
-> fn1()
(Pdb) j 6
> a.py(6)fn2()
-> print 'exception'
(Pdb) e = ValueError(5)
(Pdb) <<the rest of your debugging here>>
```

Comment: Thanks.. that's useful